# changeSize event listener in java arraylist

Tags: java, android

I am new to defining listeners. I want to know how to define a listener that fires when the size of list is changed. I know that I should first extends the ArrayList Class and then implement an interface . How to do that?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Comment: android is not swing but the theory may help you...

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to fire listener when list item is added and removed or when capacity of list changes?

Comment: I want it just when the capacity of list is changed